# Rails 6 - 524288 inotify watchers not enough to start server and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inotify

I had an error when starting `rails console`

```
FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.
Visit https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/master/README.md#increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers for info on how to fix this.
```

I have set the inotify watchers amount to 524288 as described in https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/master/README.md#increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers but that is obviously still not enough. What amount of inotify watchers does Rails 6 need ?

Thanks

Edit: Turns out the 524288 watchers are sufficient. OS is `Kubuntu 20.04` as of April, 27th, 2021

Comment: What was your solution? I am also using 524,288 watchers and still hitting the listen error. Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hello Mark Evans. I could imagine that meanwhile Rails has pumped up the count of workers and thus 524,288 aren't sufficient anymore. Typical Rails problem to me. There is no information on the amount on the official website. Sorry I can't help. :(

Comment: Von Spotz, I recently doubled my workers again to 1,048,576.  I have not had a worker issue since.